# How to handle methods which can panic?

Tags: rust, panic

What is ideomatic way of handling methods which can panic. For example take a look at next code

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = [1, 2];
    let b = v.split_at(4);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

split_at will panic because array doesn't have element at index 4, but how i can handle it as rust has not try catch

Comment: Well, in theory you can catch panics, even though it's usually not the right thing to do. Functions that panic and for which you would like to handle the error yourself usually have a `try_` version. It's not the case of this function, because in this case you can just check the length yourself beforehand.

Comment: i understand about methods which can return Result, but methods which do not return result and have no try__ is kinda stange. In this particular things one can check for len but then we can almost always do extra check i don't think this is connected to error handling

Comment: Not necessarily. Actually, there are quite a lot of functions that you don't expect that could `panic!`, but can, in some very adverse situations in which there isn't much you can do to handle the error anyways. For instance, `Box::new` can fail if there is no more memory available. In this case, there is literally nothing you can do to handle the error *except if your program has a special mode where it doesn't not require any more memory* which is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Also, `split_at` is just a wrapper around `split_at_unchecked`. Basically, `split_at` just adds a panicking check before calling `split_at_unchecked`. If you don't want to panic, you should probably not use `split_at` and write your own non-panicking check.

Comment: if you ask me this function is a design mistake and should have returned an option or result

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba5faa87ba4fd47c5836eeddfb4b1ae8

Comment: @jthulhu [`Box::try_new()` exists](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.try_new) (albeit unstably). Also, OOM does not panic by default but aborts.